# Android can't parse java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, android, timestamp

My Rest API has the following field:

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
   @Column(name = "timestamp")
   @CreationTimestamp
   private Timestamp timestamp;
```

When the following JSON is returned as a response from the API to Android:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-01-05T12:33:32.883+00:00"}
```

I am parsing it like this:

```
x.setTimestamp(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("timestamp")));
```

While the field is of type java.sql.Timestamp on both API and Android, i am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Comment: You have a `T` in the middle of the input sting that is not present in the prescribed format.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class and has some nasty surprises. For a timestamp prefer to use `timestamp with time zone` in SQL and `OffsetDateTime` in Java (`Instant` may or may not work).

Comment: If under no circumstances you can avoid the need for an old-fashioned `Timestamp` object, you may get one from `Timestamp.from(OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-01-05T12:33:32.883+00:00").toInstant())`.